# MediaMuxer playback issue with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, mediamuxer

I am using the MediaMuxer class to edit a video file for playback with the ExoPlayer library. Basically what I am doing is extracting video frames from an mp4 decoding those frames, re-encoding those frames and muxing using 
`muxer.writeSampleData(..)`

This is all fine and well and I can successfully playback a video after this is done with my ExoPlayer implementation, UNTIL the duration of the video is >= 20 seconds. When I attempt to use a video(.mp4) that is at least 20 seconds long is when the playback issue occurs. There are no errors thrown in the logs or any other exceptions for either the MediaMuxer or the ExoPlayer objects.

The issue with playback is strange, but happens in the exact same manner regardless of video length >= 20 seconds. When the playback hits the 11 seconds mark (11 seconds into the video) the frame freezes and the ExoPlayer logs indicate that the state of the player has gone from "Ready" to "Buffering" and it remains in that state indefinitely. No other errors or other relevant information is logged.

ExoPlayer logs print nothing helpful in tracking down the issue and because of this I am not sure where the issue lies. Somewhere in the video editing code where I extract the frames, decode the frames, encode the frames and mux them or in the ExoPlayer library? (the original video plays fine regardless of length) The videos that get stuck at the 11 second mark in my ExoPlayer implementation play fine on my devices default MediaPlayer.

Has anyone any experience in doing something similar? Have any ideas on where the issue might be with the experienced issues or have any any further ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the decoder would write to large of a sample in some instances and my exoplayer implementation was unable to handle it because of the max sample size I had set was too low.This was fixed by adjusting the max sample size for the decoder or the exoplayer implementation.

Comment: So how fast was the muxer in converting your video ?